# Issue in multi dimentional array unique PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Helle. I am using

```
$manual['pages'] = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $manual['pages'])));
```

and it's giving me output after making unique is

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "manuals": [],
        "versions": [],
        "pages": {
            "0": {
                "id": "25",
                "short_title": "Windows 7 Software",
                "full_title": "Windows 7 Software",
                "image": "http://marksmith.biz/media/7.jpg",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "Software"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "1": {
                "id": "26",
                "short_title": "Software: The New Paint",
                "full_title": "Software: The New Paint",
                "image": "http://marksmith.biz/media/7.jpg",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "Software"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "2": {
                "id": "27",
                "short_title": "Software: The New Wordpad",
                "full_title": "Software: The New Wordpad",
                "image": "http://marksmith.biz/media/7.jpg",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "Software"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "3": {
                "id": "28",
                "short_title": "Software: The New Calculator",
                "full_title": "Software: The New Calculator",
                "image": "http://marksmith.biz/media/7.jpg",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "Software"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "4": {
                "id": "29",
                "short_title": "Software: The New Word",
                "full_title": "Software: The New Word",
                "image": "http://marksmith.biz/media/7.jpg",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "Software"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "5": {
                "id": "30",
                "short_title": "Software: Windows Media Player 12",
                "full_title": "Software: Windows Media Player 12",
                "image": "http://marksmith.biz/media/7.jpg",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "Software"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "7": {
                "id": "11",
                "short_title": "Software Compatibility",
                "full_title": "Software Compatibility",
                "image": "http://marksmith.biz/media/7.jpg",
                "tags": []
            }
        },
        "faqs": []
    }
],
"success": "true"
```

}

Now my issue is as you can see pages array. You can find number like 0,1,2,3 etc. I want to remove that numbers from array.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: They're called indexes. Why do you want to remove them? You shouldn't need to.

Comment: yes I know that are called indexes but I am using this JSON in angular JS and it's causing me some problems so I want to remove those indexes.

Comment: If you remove them then how will you traverse the `pages` results? If you show us the code that you're using to read the JSON we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. just have to use `array_values()` and it's removed from output!